# dataTables removes row after click

Tags: jquery, datatables

I want to call a function after clicking on datatables row. However the row disappears after clicking with the error "DataTables warning: table id=dataTables-example-Requested unknown parameter '0' for row 0, column0. For more information about this error, please see http://datatables.net/tn/4"

I found my code in one of the posts:

```
    $(document).ready(function() {
        var table = $('#dataTables-example').DataTable(); 
        $('#dataTables-example tbody').on( 'click', 'tr', function () {
            var id = table.row().data(1);
            myFunction(id);
            return false;
        });
    });
```

If I put in the id hardcoded it works fine, but somehow table.row().data(1) generates the error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`data()` returns either an array or an object, and takes only params if you are about to update values. That is why you get the error, `data()` expects an array or an object when used as a setter-method. You Also you need to specify that you want `data()` from the clicked row, `row()` will just return the very first visible row on the page. So use

```
var id = table.row(this).data()[1];
```

instead.